# List comprehension vs dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

Good evening people,

I have the following code that modifies dictionary values 'in place'

```
translate1 = {k:(0 if v > 300 and v < 900 else v) for k, v in translate1.items()}
translate1 = {k:(1 if v > 1400 and v < 2100 else v) for k, v in translate1.items()}
translate1 = {k:(2 if v > 8700 and v < 9100 else v) for k, v in translate1.items()}
translate1 = {k:(3 if v > 3800 and v < 4100 else v) for k, v in translate1.items()}
translate1 = {k:(4 if v > 6400 and v < 7000 else v) for k, v in translate1.items()}
```

My question is, can a similar objective be achieved with list comprehension? I want all of the values to be in order in the same list.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is actually not being done 'in place'. An anonymous dict is created and then assigned the same name that you started with. Also, rather than run a similar dictionary comprehension 5 times, why not use a look-up function to assign the values 0-4?

Comment: You can do list comprehensions, yes. Can you show us a sample of what your result is expected to look like?

Comment: I believe comprehensions not an ideal tool here. Go with normal loopings, because you have too many conditions.

Comment: There are no in-place modifications going on here.

Answer (score 1):

List comps is no cure-all, what you need is a lookup to reduce iterating all items() 5 times down to 1 time:

```
def mapper(v):
    if 300 < v < 900:   # syntactical equivalent to v > 300 and v < 900
        return 0
    if 1400 < v < 2100:
        return 1
    if 8700 < v < 9100:
        return 2
    if 3800 < v < 4100:
        return 3
    if 6400 < v < 7000:
        return 4
    return v


translate1 = {k:mapper(v) for k, v in translate1.items()}
```

You are missing some values - I hope thats intentional.

Comment: Yes it is intentional. The unknowns are expected in the ranges specified. Thank you though, it's very helpful. helps to know he syntax changes also, that's the curse of learning via Google search I suppose. Additionally I suppose I should've been more clear, the values in the dictionary exist before the above code, they're variants all within the ranges specified but it is uncertain which key will hold what range value.

Answer (score 1):

I would write your function like so:

```
def mapper(v):
    di={
        (300,900):      0,
        (1400,2100):    1,
        (8700,9100):    2,
        (3800,4100):    3,
        (6400,7000):    4
    }
    for (t0,t1),ret in di.items():
        if t0<v<t1: return ret 
    return v

translate1={k:mapper(v) for k,v in translate1.items()}
```

That is not *materially* different than Patrick Artner's answer other than the form of the `mapper` function as a dict of tuples.

Couple of other comments:

1. The form `di={k:f(v) for k,v in di.items()}` is **not** doing in place updates on `di`. Instead the dict comprehension is first creating a new anonymous dict and then assigns that dict to the name `di` when it is done. The main issue (perhaps) is that the memory requirements for doing that are at least 2x more than in place assignment.
2. The only form of 'in-place' update with a comprehension is either:

   1. Use a slice assignment `li[:]=[list comprehension]` or
   2. Use `.update` with a dict comprehension `di.update({dict comprehension on a subset of di})`
3. There is no advantage to using a list comprehension in preference to a dict comprehension to create a dict.
4. Dict's only have any 'order' on Python 3.6+. They use insertion order in this case.